# Launching an online app: do I use CDN, Amazon Services or a dedicated server?

Tags: performance, web-applications, latency

My web application requires as little lag as possible. I have tried hosting it on a dedicated server, but users on the other side of world have complained about latency issues.

So I am considering using CDN or [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/) services.... would either help resolve this?

The application uses a lot of AJAX, so latency can be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon's [Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), part of the Amazon Web Services (AWS) that you can purchase, **is** a CDN (Content Delivery Network) -- so asking whether to use Amazon **or** "a CDN" strikes me as a weird question, akin to asking whether you should drink Coke **or** "a soda" (given that Coke *is* "a soda"). Rather you should ask "should I use Amazon or *another* CDN?" just like you'd ask "should I drink Coke or *another* soda?".

Your decision among CDNs must be based on many parameters - cost, reliability, convenience, speed, and so forth. Unfortunately I have no first-hand experience of CloudFront; however, on paper, it seems particularly simple to use (especially if you're already using other AWS components, since getting data e.g. from S3 to CloudFront is fast and cheap indeed;-), and reasonably priced (based on usage). But I have no experience about its uptime record or delivery speed.

Answer (score 0):

A content delivery network is a great idea to speed up delivery of static content (images, javascript, etc). You could even use this in combination with a dedicated server if you want.

You may also consider using a tool such as [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) to analyze what may be causing your latency issues.

Answer (score 0):

A CDN will only improve the performance of your static content -- if your Ajax code requires active content, then it won't help for that.

Amazon AWS *might* help, but it depends on the details of your application.  Amazon isn't particularly well-known for delivering a low-latency solution.

Most apps that require low latency end up addressing the issue from many directions.  A combination of a CDN and dedicated servers is certainly one approach.  One key there is choosing the right data center for your servers (a low-latency hub).

In case it might help, I wrote a book about this subject: [Ultra-Fast ASP.NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223839), which includes a discussion of client-side issues, hardware infrastructure, CDNs, caching, and many other issues that can impact latency.